# Why is my modeling and my Layout different?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

My layout is showing me something different than the modeling is showing. I don't know how to fix that.

[image]

[image]

My layout is showing me something different than the modeling is showing. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Alt H to unhide?

Comment: or / to enable/disable local view